# Show $F_{\sigma}$ finite intersection and $G_{\delta}$ finite union

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm self-studying Abbot's Understanding Analysis and I'm having trouble understanding $F_{\sigma}$ and $G_{\delta}$ sets. The question 3.5.2 is "Replace each ____ with the word `finite` or `countable` depending on which is more appropriate."

b) The ___ intersection of $F_{\sigma}$ sets is an $F_{\sigma}$ set.

c) The ___ union of $G_{\delta}$ sets is a $G_{\delta}$ set.

---

For b) I can set the problem up as:

$\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{?}\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}^{k}$

I know that the finite union of closed sets is closed and that the arbitrary intersection of closed sets is closed, but I'm not sure if (or how) I would use that to determine that the `finite` intersection is a $F_{\sigma}$ set. This would also imply that the countable intersection of $F_{\sigma}$ sets is not always a $F_{\sigma}$ set.

For c) I can set the problem up as:

$\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{?}\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}^{k}$

I think this problem follows similarly to b) hence I'm stuck here as well.

Comment: What are $F_\sigma$ and $G_\delta$ sets?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%CF%83_set

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c) is same as b) with sets replaced by their complements. In c) the right word if 'finite'. Use the fact that $\bigcap U_i \cup \bigcap V_j=\bigcap_{i,j} (U_i\cup V_j)$.

It is well known that $\mathbb Q$ is not  a $G_{\delta}$. But it is the union of singleton subbsets each of which is  a $G_{\delta}$. So 'countable' fails in c).

Comment: I'm not following your use of: $\bigcap U_i \cup \bigcap V_j=\bigcap_{i,j} (U_i\cap V_j)$, however the second part of your answer makes sense to me. Could you please point me to a resource showing how the intersection of a family of sets distributes with the union?

Comment: @varlotbarnacle There was  a typo. Now you can verify the identity by showing that each side is conatined in the other.